# Can I use HBITMAP in another thread?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

If for example I used `LoadImage()` to load a bitmap from file in Thread A, can I use the returned `HBITMAP` in Thread B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but remember a bitmap can only be selected into one DC at once. If you have two threads both drawing the same bitmap you'll need to coordinate access to it.